# What would it take to enable intellisense in a vue component's template html?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vue-component

I am relatively new to Vue, but well-versed in Typescript and Angular. I am currently going the typescript route, using the [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) and [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) libraries as prescribed by the vue docs.

I use VSCode as my editor, and, as per the title, was wondering if there are any tools/plugins/IDEs out there which allow auto-complete/intellisense in the html template. Say for example my `.ts` file is:

hi.ts:

```
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

interface IInfo {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

@Component({
  template: require('./hi.html')
})
export default HiComponent extends Vue {
  info: IInfo = { name: 'brosef', age: 30 };
}
```

hi.html:

```
<h1>name: {{ info.^ }}</h1>
<h2>age: {{ info.^ }}</h2>
```

Is there a plugin, or way to write one that could provide auto-completion options while typing this template (at the `^` positions in `hi.html` above)? Perhaps a plugin that could read a special comment at the top of a template that linked the corresponding component class...¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try [webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/),and install a typeScript plugin to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use Vuetr VSC extension as it involves all the following feature in vue file -

1. Syntax-highlighting
2. Snippet
3. Formatting
4. Linting/ Error Checking
5. Auto Completion
6. Debugging