# VSCode intellisense not working for namepsaced JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I open VSCode and create `test.js` and write something like:

```
var test = (function () {
    return {
        foo: function () {
            //foo
        },
        bar: function () {
            //foo
        }
    };
})();
```

Start typing `test` and I can see suggested for me via intellisense `foo` and `bar`, and I F12 on either it takes me to the definition.

Now if I introduce a namespace, like so:

```
var test = test || {};
test.rob = (function () {
    return {
        foo: function () {
            //foo
        },
        bar: function () {
            //foo
        }
    };
})();
```

Intellisense 'loses' the definition, doesn't highlight `foo` and `bar` and won't go to definition when using F12.

Any idea why? Have I defined my JavaScript incorrectly perhaps?

Comment: No, you haven't defined it incorrectly. (That's not a *namespace*, it's just an object, but that's just terminology.) Seems to be a bridge too far for the vscode analyzer, though. (I can replicate your results.)

Comment: [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48537587/vs-code-1-19-3-debugging-net-core-2-and-always-meet-only-64-bit-processes-can) [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538235/how-to-set-up-vue-files-formatting-in-vs-code) [Example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48536639/why-my-visual-studio-code-lacks-html) [Example 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527394/visual-studio-code-intelisense-stopped-to-work-on-c-sharp-files) [Example 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48529466/what-would-it-take-to-enable-intellisense-in-a-vue-components-template-html)

Comment: Those are just examples from the past 12 hours.

Comment: Hell, even a 6th example since I started making this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545919/visual-studio-code-nodemon-econnrefused-after-10-s-of-debugging Sorry to hijack the comments but this is kind of silly that nearly everyone seems to have problems with intellisense and debugging in Code.