# Visual Studio Code nodemon ECONNREFUSED after ~10 s of debugging

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I created a test project using `npm init` and installed TypeScript. Now I want Visual Studio to use `nodemon` for live re-attach of our debugger. According to the doc, it was installed globally using `npm install -g nodemon`. Now I see the template when trying to add a new `launch.json`configuration and the following config was added:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "nodemon",
    "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/dist/index.js",
    "restart": true,
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}
```

I also tried to go directly on the typescript files by using

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.ts",
"outFiles": [
     "${workspaceRoot}/dist/*.js"
 ]
```

The debugging works, breakpoints were reached. But it has a big problem: After about ~10 seconds of debugging, I get the following error message:

> Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:30792.)

What's the problem here? I exactly followed the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration-attributes) but couldn't make it work properly.

I only found some topics about old NodeJS versions in legacy mode. But I'm using a new one (v8.9.4) on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error and took me a while to solve it, here's my settings which eventually worked.

**package.json**

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node --inspect -r ts-node/register src/server.ts",
    "dev": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch"
  }
```

**nodemon.json**

```
{
    "ignore": ["**/*.test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts", ".git", "node_modules"],
    "watch": ["src"],
    "exec": "npm start",
    "ext": "ts, gql",
    "inspect": true,
    "events": {
        "restart": "echo \"[Warning] Remember run npm run test b4 push to dev branch !\""
    }
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach to Process",
        "port": 9229,
        "restart": true,
        "protocol": "inspector",
        // "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
        "address": "localhost"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!